# NGINX Not Reloading Configuration File

Tags: nginx

My nginx configuration file is constantly making changes that need to be reloaded.

I have tried the following, nothing but force-reload (which takes the server down temporarily) seems to work.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
sudo service nginx reload
```

Why are these not working? I get no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

First:

```
sudo kill -HUP pid (nginx pid)
```

Second:

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

Read here http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html for more details.